# Session variable not storing values

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, session

I have a session variable that i am trying to give the value from another variable (string). However, when I do this, as shown below, it does not store the value.

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();

MySqlCommand select = new MySqlCommand("SELECT personID, address_addressID from person WHERE email='" + emailAddress + "' and password = '" + passwordR + "'", connect); //brings back the person ID if user details are correct           
using (MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(select))
{
    adapter.Fill(table);

        if (table.Rows.Count != 0)
        {

            string sessionVar = table.Rows[0]["personID"].ToString();
            Session["personID"] = sessionVar;
```

the sessionVar variable is the correct data but will not input into the Session, has this been done incorrectly?

Edit: I have included some more context to make this MVCE.

Comment: Try `this.Session["personID"] = sessionVar;`.

Comment: Have you used the debugger to check the `sessionVar` variable? Also, are you using `Response.Redirect("...", true);` where that is being assigned?

Comment: Response.Redirect is being used later in the function yes, does this affect the session? And I have used the debugger and it retains the value 'personID'

Comment: You need to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Try debugging it and checking what is in the session after it's assigned. I had a similar issue before today. After, I did that it started to work.

Comment: It's storing the session name as the value for the session i.e. "personID"

Comment: @mason should have made it MVCE now.

Comment: I'm creating a session right there, the only other thing i could add related to the session is the config which just specifies a timeout for the session. There's nothing more for me to add, I imagine the problem lies with an error elsewhere in my code hence me adding more. You wouldn't be able to replicate without having access to my database so it is not simply 'irrelevant crap'.

Comment: Also hardcoded or not the value is not retained by the session variable.

Comment: @Richard1996 Exactly. If it doesn't get retained when hardcoded, then that proves my point. The database isn't related to the issue, and is just noise in your question. Making your question not minimal. Boil it down to what demonstrates the issue. No more, no less. It should be something I can paste into a new ASP.NET project and duplicate.

Comment: I don't know what else there is too add, that's the whole function almost.

Answer (score 5):

**Summary of problem:** 
When using `Response.Redirect(URL, true);` after assigning `Session` data, you'll find that it won't be stored. You need to have a `return;` on the method and use `Response.Redirect(URL, false);`.

**Explanation:**
A great explanation can be found [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/Don_2700_t-redirect-after-setting-a-Session-variable-_2800_or-do-it-right_2900_). Here's a snippet of the main part:

> When you create a new session (that is, the first time you write to a Session variable), ASP.NET sets a volatile cookie on the client that contains the session token. On all subsequent requests, and as long as the server session and the client cookie have not expired, ASP.NET can look at this cookie and find the right session.
> Now, what Redirect does is to send a special header to the client so that it asks the server for a different page than the one it was waiting for. Server-side, after sending this header, Redirect ends the response. This is a very violent thing to do. Response.End actually stops the execution of the page wherever it is using a ThreadAbortException.
> What happens really here is that the session token gets lost in the battle.

Comment: Just tested and it still seems to not be storing the value, must be another issue?

Comment: You've used `Response.Write(URL, false);`? Perhaps the Session may have timed out? Check what your timeout is set to within the web.config file. You can check in the browser cookie settings to see if the ASP.NET Session ID changes.

Comment: My timeout is set to 20 minutes and the session all works correctly, except for it does not assign my required value to it (the 'sessionVar' variable)

Comment: Have you added a breakpoint and gone through each line to check that it's actually being called? Also, try adding an additional variable right after that to see if it's an issue with redirection or that specific one

Comment: Yes I've done this to start with, I get the same value as the name 'personID', the session itself is created but the correct value is not given. I have removed my redirect completely to no avail. When I insert a break point after assignment, the value is not changed.

Comment: I've included some more of my code to hopefully help locate the source of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to access the session values in that same request context, but not on subsequent requests?

The default Asp.net implementation is to store the session ID in a cookie so it can be accessed on subsequent requests. After creating the session, check your browser cookies to see if the session ID exists. Chrome does not store the cookies for insecure sites, so if you are running from local host, you may want to test with a different browser.

How to see localhost cookies in Edge:
[image]

See this answer regarding storing cookies for insecure sites in chrome:
[Cookies no longer save for insecure sites in Google Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46308187/cookies-no-longer-save-for-insecure-sites-in-google-chrome)